# create nested dictionary from keys list

Tags: python

I have list of keys: `list1 =['info', 'websites', 'site']` and a final value = 'check'.
I'm trying to build a recursive function that create a nested dictionary as follows:

```
dict = {'info': {'websites': {'site' : 'check' } } }
```

I tried the following function but my function doesn't get the above output:

```
def nested_dict(keys_list, value, check_dict, size):
    if size != 1:
        print(check_dict)
        check_dict[keys_list[0]] = nested_dict(keys_list[1:], value, check_dict, size-1)
    else:
        print(check_dict)
        check_dict[keys_list[0]] = value
        return check_dict
```

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Is your indentation correct? In case of `if` you are not returning anything

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need for recursion. This will work:

```
list1 = ['info', 'websites', 'site']

def nested_dict(keys_list, value):
    for key in reversed(keys_list):
        value = {key: value}
    return value

print(nested_dict(list1, 'check'))
```

gives:

```
{'info': {'websites': {'site': 'check'}}}
```

If you use recursion, there is a danger of exceeding the maximum recursion depth for long lists, for little advantage.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why you are using so many arguments in your `nested_dict` function. You don't need them there. This simple example gives me the result you are looking for:

```
def nested_dict(keys):
    if(len(keys) == 1):
        return {keys[0]: 'check'}
    else:
        return {keys[0]: nested_dict(keys[1:])}

key_list = ['info', 'websites', 'site']

print(nested_dict(key_list))
```

Also, yes, as has been posted above you don't need recursion to do just this. But for my answer I assumed you need the recursion for another part of your project anyway.

Comment: Yes, thank you for this answer. Although I thought it is helpful to show an answer without recursion, it is also helpful to show how the recursive solution can be implemented properly.

Comment: That said, you might also like to look at sushant's answer. There is a slightly different stop condition, and that one allows for the possibility of an empty list of keys, which yours doesn't.

Comment: Ah, yes, that is a good point, thanks :)!

Answer (score 4):

A functional approach using [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=reduce#functools.reduce):

```
from functools import reduce

lst = ['info', 'websites', 'site']

result = reduce(lambda x, y: {y: x}, reversed(lst), "check")
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{'info': {'websites': {'site': 'check'}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use recursive function like so:

```
>>> list1 =['info', 'websites', 'site']

def nested_dict(l, value):
    if not l:
        return value
    else:
        return {l[0]: nested_dict(l[1:])}

>>> nested_dict(list1, 'check')
{'info': {'websites': {'site': 'check'}}}
```